# Visual editor WordPress deformats code link embedding YouTube-video

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I can embed a YouTube-video by just putting the URL in the HTML-code with some space around it (see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), like:

```
<tr><td>

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx

</td></tr>
```

This works. But if I open the page with the visual editor and save it the code is deformated like:

```
<tr><td>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
```

and a link is shown in the webpage instead of the (embedded) video. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Proper HTML note here - You should NOT be using blank lines for formatting anyway. The correct way to put in multiple blank lines would be

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

or
    `<br style="clear:both;" />`

If you're using the GUI text editor, TinyMCE Advanced may help, as it supposedly has an option to kill that.

This is what I've found on the wordpress forum. Hope it helps.